# PDO class not found on shared hosting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php-5.6

I have a code which had been working on PHP 5.4 but not working on PHP 5.6.
some problems with PDO. My code is here:

```
<?php
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 999604800);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 999604800);

$baseurl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
$hostname = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

//if(!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) { die('PDO unavailable'); }

class connect_data {

    static $host = 'localhost'; //хост базы данных
    static $username = 'aqq13807'; //логин базы данных
    static $password = 'd,8p9\FP%kZDZ)R'; //пароль базы данных
    static $db = 'aqq13807_d1'; //имя базы данных

}

class sql {
bla-bla-bla
}

$sql = new sql();

class pdo_connector {

    //const DBNAME = 'aqq13807_d1'; //имя базы данных
    //const DBLOGIN = 'root'; //логин базы данных
    //const DBPASS = 'aq798803'; //пароль базы данных

    const MINIMUM_PHP = '5.1.0';

    private function check_version() {

        if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, self::MINIMUM_PHP, '<')) {

            return 'На вашем сервере должна быть установлена версия PHP ' . self::MINIMUM_PHP . ' или выше для работы с коннектором PDO!';

        }

    }

    public static function transaction($query = null, $op_type) {

        self::check_version();

        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.connect_data::$db, connect_data::$username, connect_data::$password, array( PDO :: ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ));
        }
```

And I have error when I trying "use PDO" -

> Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'PDO' has no effect
>   in bla-bla/testpdo.php on line 3
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at bla-bla/config.php on line 2

I also trying to write something like \PDO but It also doesn't work. I had been also trying to load pdo via php.ini like this

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525"
extension = "xcache.so"
extension = "pdo.so"
extension = "pdo_sqlite.so"
extension = "imagick.so"
extension = "pdo_mysql.so"
```

But It's not also working, so I cheked phpinfo, It looks like evething ok with PDO.

Comment: You don't need to `use PDO`. It's automatically included.

Comment: I don't actually see `use PDO` in that script anyway..?!

Comment: What's on line 3 of testpdo.php?

Comment: I was trying to "use PDO" after each of first a few rows before "class connect_data"

Comment: testpdo.php

`<?php

require_once './include/config.php';

$getVal = pdo_connector::transaction("SELECT * FROM drivers_profile", 'select');

var_dump($getVal);`

Comment: Check if you have the `extension=pdo.so` set in `php.ini`. Don't forget to check te appropriate driver in `php.ini`, like `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`. More on [php help site](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php).

Comment: echo phpinfo() and search for pdo extension

Comment: Yes, I also checked It, there is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, question has been finished, a problem was php.ini file, It was removed and then everything works fine. I don't know why, but my hosting notice me about this action with a file.